# Filtering Data with Duplicates (Google Sheets) but the cell values next to them are different

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets. First one is the [IN Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X29Qo.png) which contains name, license, and time and the second one is the [cxz Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5XH5.png) which also contains the same name and license but different time. I want to align those who have the same name and license but different time.

I used `=Filter(cxz!A2:D, B#= cxz!A2:A)` [example codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xINho.png). Here is the [result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNolQ.png) How do I remove the #REF! error in the result and align it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're facing comes from the fact that FILTER will return multiple rows if you have multiple ins and Outs, as it's the case from Joyce3. The #REF error means in this case that the formula is trying to expand but can't because there's another formula below.

If you have multiple ins and outs, and they're not as well aligned as in this case, I suggest you create a new column that creates a kind of unique ID for that row. For example, the name and number of appearance with MAP and COUNTIF:

```
=MAP(B2:B,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",each&"--"&COUNTIF(B2:each,each))))
```

This will create a new column where the first Joyce3 will have it's "ID" as Joyce3--1 and the second appearance as Joyce3--2. Then, let's say you create that column in M in IN and J in OUT. Then you can safely use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(IN!A:D,IN!M:M=J3)
```

Or even more efficiently INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(IN!A:D,MATCH(J3,IN!M:M,0))
```